# middleware not executed on 404

Tags: django

We have middleware that records the last url the user has visited:

```
class LastSiteUrl(object):

    def is_admin_url(self, url):
        if re.search('^(http:\/\/.*){0,1}\/admin\/', url) is None: return(False)
        else: return(True)

    def process_request(self, request):
        if self.is_admin_url(request.path) and \
            not self.is_admin_url(request.META['HTTP_REFERER']):
            request.session['last_site_url'] = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
```

We use this to return them back to the last app page they were at,
from an admin page, no matter how deep into admin they were. This is
working fine.

We have a custom 404 page, and from there I want to provide a link to
take them back to where they were in the app. But it seems the
middleware does not run when they go to an invalid page. Is there a
way to make it run in that case as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you use handler404 in your base urls.py you can serve your 404 page from a django view instead of straight from the server, and add that middleware the way you would to any other django view.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.handler404

in urls.py

```
handler404 = 'app.views.view'
```

or

```
handler404 = ClassView.as_view()
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this was the answer 10 years ago, but I've encountered the same issue myself and found that Abdul Aziz Barkat's answer to my question, " [Why is the Middleware not processed on 404 page in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73070115/why-is-the-middleware-not-processed-on-404-page-in-django) " was the right answer for me: to use a [custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) instead of middleware.

The answers suggesting using `handler404` led me down a long and unproductive rabbit hole.