# Why is the Middleware not processed on 404 page in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, middleware

So I've set up a path in my URL config:

```py
path(
    "kitten/",
    views.Kitten.as_view(),
    name="kitten",
),
```

and a handler for missing URLs to the same view.

```py
handler404 = views.Kitten.as_view()
```

I have some middleware which sets some context data:

```py
class CookieConsentMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        response.context_data["hasCookie"] = False        
        return response
```

and the view is very straightforward,

```py
class Kitten(TemplateView):
    template_name = "kitten.html"
```

and the template prints the value of `hasCookie`.

Visiting `kitten/` correctly displays the value of `hasCookie`, but visiting a URL that doesn't exist, displays no value for hasCookie (whilst showing the right template)

Adding debugging statements to the middleware, it becomes apparent that whilst `process_view`, `process_template_response` and `process_exception` are called for `kitten/`, none of these are called for URLs that don't exist, so no code is called to set the value of `hasCookie`. (`__init__` is called regardless at app startup)

**Why does it not call the middleware when the URL is not found in the URLconf?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middleware does get called but not its `process_template_response` method since Django calls the render function on the response from the exception handler making it not a `TemplateResponse` object anymore. This can be seen in the [code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f81032572107846922745b68d5b7191058fdd5f5/django/core/handlers/exception.py#L152-L156) for the `response_for_exception` function:

> ```py
> # Force a TemplateResponse to be rendered.
> if not getattr(response, "is_rendered", True) and callable(
>     getattr(response, "render", None)
> ):
>     response = response.render()
> ```

This is because `response_for_exception` is called by `convert_exception_to_response` which needs to do ensure the response is rendered since it wraps both the first and the last middleware in the chain.

It seems you are using the middleware to add values to your context, which is not the best place to do this. You should instead write a [custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) which will be called consistently.